# Serial communication with Window(python) and linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, window, pyserial

I am trying for serial communication for two different OS. One is Ubuntu linux and the other is Window. I am using python in window and I am simply using basic serial command in Ubuntu.

What I intended was simple. If I send any message from linux to window, I see a message from window python screen. After that the python will automatically respond a message and it should be appear to the terminal. I made two kinds of python scripts and I will also attach the linux commands which I used.

Python script from window.

```
import serial
import time
Xserial=serial.Serial('C0M4',9600)

data='Received\n'
while(True):
    if(Xserial.readable()):
    print(Xserial.readline())
    Xserail.write(data.encode())
    time.sleep(1)

Xserial.close()
```

Linux command I am using

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb

echo "HELLO" > /dev/ttyUSB0 

cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

In the Ubuntu terminal screen, I see hundreds of same messages such as

```
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
Received
...
```

In Window, I see such message as

```
b'HELLO\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
b'Received\r\n'
...
```

I thought this was a problem with serial buffer written in the port, so I modified my python script like

```
import serial
import time
Xserial=serial.Serial('C0M4',9600)

data='Received\n'
while(True):
    if(Xserial.readable());
    print(Xserial.readline())
    Xserail.write(data.encode())
    Xserail.flushOutput()
    time.sleep(1)

Xserial.close()
```

But it still does not work. I don't see any message from Ubuntu but I see a message such as

```
b'HELLO\r\n'
b'RHELLO\r\n'
```

b'RHELLO\r\n' appears when I command echo "HELLO" > /dev/ttyUSB0 for the second time.
I don't see any message in the linux terminal.

I cannot use pyserial in Ubuntu because this linux commands will be implemented in my C++ script in the future. Is there any way to fix this?